# What does "fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born" mean in this context

Tags: git, git-checkout

I was migrating a svn repo to git. I created a clean temp dir, used git svn init to get stuff in there and then added the remote and pushed it. Now on the other actual source dir (which I had cloned from the empty repo before committing stuff from svn)  I did a fetch. And then I did a checkout and got above message. After a while I figured that I could get the source with a pull and did that. My question is what did that error message mean in that context ? How did I get that particular error message ?
Disclaimer : I am a git newbie

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my 'git branch' have no master?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623755/why-does-my-git-branch-have-no-master)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe it was because your fetch, which only fetches remote refs and commits, didn't give you a local *master* branch to checkout.  Since you were in an empty repo, you were never on a branch, so your `git checkout` had no *master* branch to go to.

You could directly checkout the remote master by explicitly naming it with `git checkout origin/master` but that will leave you in a detached head state.

Once you did the pull, it fetched **and** merged, the pull created a local *master* to track the remote master.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error trying to migrate svn to git.  Here was my fix.

Confirm you've initialized the git repo:

```
git init
```

Confirm you actually had a valid migration from svn:

```
git branch --remote

#You should see this output:
#git-svn
```

Create a detached head:

```
git checkout git-svn
```

Convert the detached head into the master branch:

```
git checkout -b master
```

At this point your git repo will function normally.