# "Cannot update paths and switch to branch at the same time"

Tags: git, git-checkout

I sometimes use the `checkout -b` option to create a new branch, check it out at the same time and set up tracking in one command.

In a new environment, I get this error:

```
$ git checkout -b test --track origin/master
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'test' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/master' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

Why does Git not like it? This used to work with the same repo.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `origin/master` is not a commit ID, i.e., not a valid remote branch.  Does it show up in `git branch -r` output?

Comment: It didn't. Turns out I didn't check out all remote branches during clone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git checkout on a remote branch does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945654/git-checkout-on-a-remote-branch-does-not-work)

Answer (score 219, accepted):

> '`origin/master`' which can not be resolved as commit

Strange: you need to check your remotes:

```
git remote -v
```

And make sure `origin` is fetched:

```
git fetch origin
```

Then:

```
git branch -avv
```

(to see if you do have fetched an `origin/master` branch)

Finally, use [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) instead of the [confusing `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), with Git 2.23+ (August 2019).

```
git switch -c test --track origin/master
```

Comment: I had a typo in my command which triggered this error; I wasn't spelling my remote correctly!

Comment: It was a new branch and my local repository didn't knew about it. I had to do a `pull` and then this command worked.

Comment: This answer was helpful because it showed me that there’s really something weird going on: Remotes are set correctly, but the new remote branch is simply not fetched. When I clone the remote in a clean directory, it works. Could my `.git` directory be somehow corrupt?

Comment: git remote -v returned this error fatal: Not a valid object name: 'remote'.

Comment: @KarimSamir you could ask a separate question (with your OS and git version), as `git remote -v` executed in a git repo does work.

Comment: did a `git pull --rebase` on master branch to fix this

Comment: Basically you should `git fetch target-remote` before `git checkout -b branch target-remote/branch`.

Comment: @RuslanMakrenko Yes, I always like to do a fetch: it does not change your index or working tree, and it makes sure your remote is up-to-date.

Answer (score 98):

If you have a typo in your branchname you'll get this same error.

Comment: Actually it would be nice if someone could take the time to tell Git developers about this, the error message is not very informative ;)

Comment: yes , this was my problem , I had a space in my  branch name

Comment: Same here, I was trying `git checkout -b origin mybranch` instead of `git checkout -b mybranch` (extra `origin`)

Comment: I copy-pasted my branch name and had trailing whitespace after the branch name which caused this error.

Comment: I was trying to checkout `orgin/my-branch` instead of `origin/my-branch`. Missed one `i` & I kept scratching my head for a while to understand why an old ally is refusing to get along. Typo indeed was the issue.

Comment: oversight is real. thank you!

Answer (score 62):

You can get this error in the context of, e.g. a Travis build that, by default, checks code out with `git clone --depth=50 --branch=master`. To the best of my knowledge, you can control `--depth` via `.travis.yml` but not the `--branch`. Since that results in only a single branch being tracked by the remote, you need to independently update the remote to track the desired remote's refs.

Before:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
```

The fix:

```
$ git remote set-branches --add origin branch-1
$ git remote set-branches --add origin branch-2
$ git fetch
```

After:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/branch-1
remotes/origin/branch-2
remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: Solved it for me. I used a shallow --depth=1 clone and this is what I needed to switch branches.

Comment: Gah yes, the depth thing definitely results in this error! If possible, I would suggest that the first few sentences be edited to emphasize the depth thing.

Comment: From git-config side, you can achieve a similar effect by adding a new `[branch]` entry and a `fetch` line under the relevant `[remote]` entry in `.git/config`

Answer (score 26):

This simple thing worked for me!

If it says it can't do 2 things at same time, separate them.

```
git branch branch_name origin/branch_name 

git checkout branch_name
```

Comment: Makes it easy to find out what the real problem is

Answer (score 10):

You could follow these steps when you stumble upon this issue:

1. Run the following command to list the branches known for your local repository.

> git remote show origin

which outputs this:

> ```
>  remote origin
>   Fetch URL: <your_git_path>
>   Push  URL: <your_git_path>
>   HEAD branch: development
>   Remote branches:
>     development                             tracked
>     Feature2                                tracked
>     master                                  tracked
>     refs/remotes/origin/Feature1         stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
>   Local branches configured for 'git pull':
>     Feature2     merges with remote Feature2
>     development  merges with remote development
>     master       merges with remote master
>   Local refs configured for 'git push':
>     Feature2     pushes to Feature2     (up to date)
>     development  pushes to development (up to date)
>     master       pushes to master      (local out of date)
> ```

2. After verifying the details like (fetch URL, etc), run this command to fetch any new branch(i.e. which you may want to checkout in your local repo) that exist in the remote but not in your local.

> ```
> » git remote update
>
> Fetching origin
> From gitlab.domain.local:ProjectGroupName/ProjectName
>  * [new branch]      Feature3    -> Feature3
> ```

As you can see the new branch has been fetched from remote. 
3. Finally, checkout the branch with this command

> ```
> » git checkout -b Feature3 origin/Feature3
>
> Branch Feature3 set up to track remote branch Feature3 from origin.
> Switched to a new branch 'Feature3'
> ```

It is not necessary to explicitly tell Git to track(using **--track**) the branch with remote.

The above command will set the local branch to track the remote branch from origin.

Answer (score 9):

If you got white space in your branch then you will get this error.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I accidentally had a space in my branch name:

```
git checkout -b my-branch-name-with a-space
                                   ▲
        accidental space ──────────┘
```

Deal with the space.

Answer (score 2):

It causes by that your local branch doesn't track remote branch.
As ssasi said,you need use these commands:

```
git remote update
git fetch
git checkout -b branch_nameA origin/branch_nameB
```

I solved my problem just now....

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to update my local git repository with latest tags from remote repository using below command:

```
git fetch --tags
```

The command to fetch remote repository tags may differ based on your organization's Git setup.

After doing this, `git checkout` worked.

Answer (score 2):

First You need check your remote : It should be *master

```
git pull (up-to-date)
git checkout -b branch-name (branch name without any spaces)
git status
git add .
git commit -m "comments goes here"
git push branch-name
```

Comment: The no spaces here in the branch name is what was causing it for me.

Comment: I had spaces too in the branch's name. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me I needed to add the remote:

```
git remote -add myRemoteName('origin' in your case) remoteGitURL
```

then I could fetch

```
git fetch myRemoteName
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to `Fetch` the remote (the specific branch), then you can create a local br and track it with that remote branch using your command (i.e. `checkout` with -b and --track).

Answer (score 0):

You should go the submodule dir and run `git status`.

You may see a lot of files were deleted. You may run

1. `git reset .`
2. `git checkout .`
3. `git fetch -p`
4. `git rm --cached submodules` //submoudles is your name
5. `git submoudle add ....`

Answer (score 0):

You can use these commands:
git remote update,
git fetch,
git checkout -b branch_nameA origin:branch_nameB

I think maybe it's because of your local branch can not track remote branch

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I tap this line to create a new branch from my remote branch:

```
git checkout -b newbranch origin/ remotebranch
```

To fix that you can first update your local repository by:

```
fetch --all
```

Then correctly enter your command again :

```
git checkout -b newbranch origin/remotebranch
```

Please make sure to spell everything correctly and dont put space between origin/ and remotebranch. Those steps helped me to solve my issue.