# How to create a branch locally and push it to remote (fork repo) from Upstream

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I have forked(origin) a repo from another repo (Upstream).

What I want to do is,

1. Creating a local branch called **UnitTest** from **Upstream/develop_clean** branch.
2. Push it to a remote branch called **UnitTest**

What I have done is

```
git checkout -b UnitTest upstream/develop_clean
git push -u origin UnitTest
```

But it throws a fatal error like

> fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'UnitTest' at the same
>   time. Did you intend to checkout 'upstream/develop_clean' which can
>   not be resolved as commit?

I can not figure it out. Whats the problem here? 
Is there any other ways to do the same thing as describe above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cannot update paths and switch to branch at the same time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984262/cannot-update-paths-and-switch-to-branch-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

'upstream/develop_clean' is not getting resolved, you might need to check your remotes :

```
git remote -v
```

Then fetch origin :

```
git fetch origin
```

Comment: git remote -v outputs `origin  https://github.com/nalam-nmef/NextGenTPR.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/nalam-nmef/NextGenTPR.git (push)
upstream        https://github.com/NMEF/NextGenTPR.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/NMEF/NextGenTPR.git (push)
`