# You are on a branch yet to be born

Tags: git

Im have strange problem:

```
$ cd ~/htdocs

$ mkdir test

$ cd test

$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/deep/htdocs/test/.git/

$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

$ git checkout -b master
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born

$ git checkout origin/master
error: pathspec 'origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

$ git branch -a
(empty this)
```

But this is new local empty repo. Where is master branch?

Comment: check it here https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623755/why-does-my-git-branch-have-no-master

Comment: I accidentally ran npm version patch on the parent folder which I think is what messed up all my projects

Answer (score 45):

As ever, Git is right, it just has a quirky way of saying it: when you create a repository, the master branch actually doesn't exist yet because there's nothing for it to point to.

Have you tried committing something after your `git init`? Adding a remote and pulling from it will also work, of course.

Comment: I added a remote and pulled from it and I still got this error. Simply just doing a quick add . / commit I was able to get to branches

Comment: but if i don't want to pull anything from master?

Comment: @Cocuba I think you don`t have to pull from master, it says when your just init your git repo, you should make your first commits to create a branch, before you can checkout, since branch have not been created.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem as you. The way I solved was creating a new empty file just to have a file in the project.

`git add someFile` then `commit -m "first commit"` and finally with `push origin master`

i hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

If someone reaches this part, I think you have no luck with the top answers. I got the same situation with OP too. Try this:

1. Pull your repo in another directory
2. copy .git folder to your new repo

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are uploading the git repository which has `main` as it default branch. But on bare repository the default branch is `master`. To fix this problem easy way, remove the base repository.
Run the following command.

`git config --global init.defaultBranch main`
Then create again the bare repository using the following command.

`git init --bare`

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to initialize a new repo without actually committing any files:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initialization"
```

If you happen to have `--bare` repo, then the workaround is as this:

```
mkdir /tmp/empty_directory
git --work-tree=/tmp/empty_directory checkout --orphan master
git --work-tree=/tmp/empty_directory commit --allow-empty -m "Initialization"
rm -rf /tmp/empty_directory
```

Comment: This works for me with the additional step of forcibly updating the new `master` branch to what I was trying to make it in the first place (in my case via `git push -f` from another repo with the new one as a remote). This abandoned the pro forma commit, but I never wanted it in the first place, so whatever.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you wanted to

```
git init
```

in the root folder where you have the *.gitignore* file.
Create a subfolder and try there.

Answer (score 1):

Try add the branch in the end

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="/home/user/repo"
GIT_DIR="/home/user/www.git"
BRANCH="master"
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
 # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
 if [ "$ref" = "refs/heads/$BRANCH" ];
 then
  echo "Ref $ref received. Deploying ${BRANCH} branch to production..."
  git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f $BRANCH
 else
  
  # perform more tasks like migrate and run test, the output of these commands will be shown on the push screen
echo "Ref $ref received. Doing nothing: only the ${BRANCH} branch may be deployed on this server."
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when I had multiple Windows Explorers open, both opened to the same existing local git repo.

I created a new branch in one window, by using right-click --> create branch.

Later, in the 2nd instance of Windows Explorer, I attempted to right click --> Branch (to find out which branch was currently checked out).  I then got the message "You are on a branch yet to be born".

Simply closing the 2nd Explorer ended the problem, and the error did not show up in the 1st Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the OP.  Initially, I did the following:

```
md Project
cd Project
git init
git remote add origin git@domain.com:user/repo.git
```

All subsequent `git` commands had the same errors as the OP.

What worked for me was to delete the Project folder, and then issue the following command from the parent folder:

```
git clone http[s]://domain.com/user/repo.git Project
```

It then prompted me for my username and password to access the repo.  Every `git` command asked for credentials, so I ran the following command:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

The next `git` command asked for my credentials, which were then stored in the **Windows Credential Manager** (visible via the **Control Panel**).  Now `git` commands work without prompting for credentials.