# How can I commit my .vim contents to a git repo

Tags: git, vim, github, vim-plugin

When I started learning git recently, I thought it would be a good idea to put all my .vim contents on Github (my vimrc file and the scripts I use), commiting then when they work well, and doing resets when they don't.

Everything worked fine until I did a change in a script. It's not a script made by me, it is a script I installed via Vundle (to be precise, the [vim-trailing-whitespace](https://github.com/bronson/vim-trailing-whitespace)). I just change some color name in the script, and everytime I do a `git status`, it shows:

```
andre@andre:~/.vim$ git status
No ramo master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (utilize "git add <arquivo>..." para atualizar o que será submetido)
  (utilize "git checkout -- <arquivo>..." para descartar mudanças no diretório de trabalho)
  (submeter ou descartar o conteúdos não monitorados ou modificados em submódulos)

    modificado: bundle/vim-trailing-whitespace (conteúdo modificado)

nenhuma modificação adicionada à submissão (utilize "git add" e/ou "git commit -a")
```

After a `git add .` or `git add -A` I receive no return (normal, I guess).

But after a `git commit -m "Improved mapping, included saving with sudo tee in map, fixed indent lines"` I receive the same:

```
andre@andre:~/.vim$ sudo git commit -m "Improved mapping, included saving with sudo tee in map, fixed indent lines"
No ramo master
Changes not staged for commit:
    modificado: bundle/vim-trailing-whitespace (conteúdo modificado)

nenhuma modificação adicionada à submissão
```

So, why my `git add .` is not adding to stage? I have some clues, but no answer.

### EDIT:

When I ran a `git diff` I get:

```
diff --git a/bundle/vim-trailing-whitespace b/bundle/vim-trailing-whitespace
--- a/bundle/vim-trailing-whitespace
+++ b/bundle/vim-trailing-whitespace
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 478b217d299b6f5938b43a4929d6bb0907cc3a56
+Subproject commit 478b217d299b6f5938b43a4929d6bb0907cc3a56-dirty
```

Why these subprojects are there? I never "made" them, I just install scripts with Vundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Actually, these steps might solve your problem (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24034199/4694621)):

```
git checkout -b tempbranch
git clone https://github.com/user/yourrepo --branch tempbranch
git checkout -b master
git update-ref HEAD master
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

#### Tips on Vim plugins

I don't think that uploading plugins to your repo is a good idea. Upload only your files, and if you need to run Vim on a different computer then install your Vundle plugins with `:PluginInstall` inside Vim.

If you really want to add plugins to your repo, you might consider adding them as git modules.

#### What's happening with your Git

When it comes to Git it seems like **you're missing the master branch**. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623755/why-does-my-git-branch-have-no-master):

- When you have a remote repository:

  > To checkout branch which not exists locally but is in the remote repo
  >   you could use this command:
  >
  > `git checkout -t -b master origin/master`
- When you're working locally:

  > Most Git repositories use master as the main (and default) branch - if you initialize a new Git repo via git init, it will have master checked out by default.

  Or you can create the master branch like this:

  ```
  git checkout -b master
  ```

Comment: When I ran `git checkout -t -b master origin/master` I get: `fatal: A branch with the name 'master' already exists.` You see, I added some new stuff in my local machine and I pushed than easily. They're on my repository now. But the modified 'vim-trailing-whitespace' just don't want to go, it continues not staged.

Comment: The same described above. Check out the edit I did in the question... maybe it helps.

Comment: Subproject looks suspicious :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088781/what-does-subproject-commit-mean

Comment: My guess (wild guess) is that when I install a script with Vundle it remains linked with the repository. In fact, I know that when the author update his/her script, Vundle automatically update it in my machine. So... I transformed my .vim folder in a local Git repository, changed a script and try to push it... maybe Github is saying "hey, you can't alter a script that is not yours." With this explanation you can see I really don't understand Git a lot XD. But... maybe I'm right?

Comment: Well, certainly something is messed up here. However I don't know much about submodules yet, so I cannot help you more with this particular issue. For the time being, I recommend you not to push everything to your GitHub repo - it is muuuch better to keep your plugins  being managed by Vundle.